# advice on replacing text in <label> by using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need advice on what is the best way to change the text surrounded by `<label>`.

The output from my php back-end looks like the code below in browser.

I need to find a way to change the Text inside each `<label>` to different text for each `<label>`
for example: Text to change1 = aaaa , Text to change2 = bbbb, etc.

It is like 53 blocks that need to be changed, so I'm thinking what would be the best approach in Jquery?
I know the `replace()` but would I then have to use it 53 times or?
can some one advise?

```
<div class="pageoverflow">
  <p class="pagetext">
    <label for="customfield_35">
       Text to change1
    </label>
    <input>
  </p>
</div>


<div class="pageoverflow">
  <p class="pagetext">
    <label for="customfield_36">
       Text to change2
    </label>
    <input>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="pageoverflow">
  <p class="pagetext">
    <label for="customfield_37">
       Text to change3
    </label>
    <input>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is changing the source code not an option?

Comment: no its not :(   thats why Im thinking of Jquery

Comment: What is the pattern for determining what value should be replaced by what other value?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, but the labels all have different for=""  so I whas thinking maybe I could use that somehow to change the text

Comment: Your question states (*Text to change1 = aaaa , Text to change2 = bbbb, etc.*).  I'm asking what the pattern is for all the 53 or whatever instances.

Comment: Im sorry, I shouldn't have put aaaa, bbbb, (it looks like a pattern).  Each text will change to another text. Which is manually inserted, there is no pattern. Just text changing to another text

Comment: So if there isn't a pattern, and you're going to be defining what each value should be for all 53 instances, what's the issue with targeting each label and just changing their `text()` or `innerText`?

Comment: well that is basically what I was looking for, if there is another approach to this than targeting each label

Comment: Not if there is not a pattern to what the logic should do.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to accomplish. What is the source data? What is the target data? Are you trying to identify a specific text pattern or do it based on the attributes of the label? Look at `$("label").each()` type of loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var items = $('.pageoverflow');
var increment = 1111; //dummy replacement value
if (items.length) { //as array starts from 0
    $( items ).each(function( index ) { //foreach every block
        var element = $('label',this); //get label information
        $('label[for='+element.attr('for')+']').text(increment); //replacing text based on for attribute_name
        increment = increment+100; //dummy value change for reference
    });
}
</script>
```